# jquery & Css - Edit a certain id

Tags: jquery

I have a div with this id (in ipboard) :

```
<div id="pane_members:status">
```

How do I define a style for this div or id in a **.css** file?
or (edit this code and add style attribute) with some jQuery methods.

rather than use style attribute in HTML element

Comment: If you have a static design then add it to an external css file, you do not have to use jquery. Use this syntax #pane_members:status {}

Comment: Did you link the css file in your html file? how is your css file looks like?

Comment: do you have a .css file? you would do something like `#pane_members:status { *css code* }` in your css file - or with jquery...you can use the `.css` function - but there is no reason for that if you can just have a regular css file and import it in index.html

Comment: in head tag : `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../test.css">`

in body:
`<div id="test:status">test</div>`

in external css file (test.css):
`body{background:blue;}
#test:status {
  display:none;
}`
but its not working.just page's background color is blue and " test " is visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a backslash \ before semicolon:

```
#test\:status {display: none;}
```

Or:

```
#test\3A status {   Display:none; }
```

[Using Namespaces with CSS - Microsoft MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762307%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this great tool 
http://jsfiddle.net/3kASW/

```
test_status {   display:none; }
```

Apparently, the Colon ':' is not supported for css. It is supported for the html value, but not for the css (I Guess because the css uses those colon for other uses like 'hover')